# How to obtain a value from a df irrespective if the user input has capital letter or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` as follows:

```
    BDEW    Article
0   999     Cola
1   998     Fanta
2   997     Sprite
3   996     Dew
4   995     Water
```

We can see that the first letter of each article in the `Article` column starts with a capital letter. I am asking user to select an article. If the user enters the name with a capital letter at start, my code it works fine. But if the user gives input as `cola` instead of `Cola`, i get an error:

> Do you want to add a segment (Y/N)?: y
>
> Which article would you like to add?: cola Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File "", line 5, in 
>       bdew_value = df.loc[df['Article'] == article, 'BDEW'].iloc[0]
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 1410, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 2132, in _getitem_axis
>       self._validate_integer(key, axis)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py",
>   line 2063, in _validate_integer
>       raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
>
> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

I think that the error is because I am using `.iloc` in my code.

Is there a way I can overcome this problem such that even if the user inserts a name with a small letter at the start, the code should work.

**My code:**

```
i = 0
while True:
    add_seg = input('Do you want to add a segment (Y/N)?: ')
    if (add_seg == 'Y')|(add_seg == 'y'):
        article = (input('Which article would you like to add?: ')).lower()
        bdew_value = df.loc[df['Article'] == article, 'BDEW'].iloc[0]
        i = i + 1
        INVOIC.add_segment(Segment('LIN', str(i), '', [str(bdew_value), 'Z01']))

    elif (add_seg == 'N')|(add_seg == 'n'):
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the input given by the user in uppercase then do your comparisons. Something like:

`article = (input('Which article would you like to add?: ')).upper()`

You said that, for the program to work, the first letter needs to be an uppercase letter. So I guess the rest doesn't matter.

Or, if you want, you can only convert the first letter into caps:

`article = (input('Which article would you like to add?: ')).capitalize()`

Comment: `.capitalize()` works well. thank you. I will accept the answer

Comment: I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears the filtering returns no line, *i.e.* `df.loc[df['Article'] == article, 'BDEW']` returns an empty dataframe. You could replace `.iloc[0]` with `.get(0)`, then control that `bdew_value` is not `None`, and when it is, prompt the user again, mentioning that no match was found for the previous input.

Now, the reason for the filtering returning no line is that you should `.captialize` the input (or `.lower` the `'Article'` column) for the casings to be matching. But please do consider the former paragraph, in general, even when the specific issue encountered in this case is fixed.

I hope this helps :-)